# Exception thrown while unbinding at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal

Tags: android

I get this exception but I do not know how to find what the issue is nor what causes it. Can you help?

```
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@c26f865
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1331)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1495)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:648)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>The solution is to add</s>

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
```

in your app-level build Gradle dependency.

**UPDATE**: This is just a minor logcat warning and should not have any effect on your app. It is a bug and the team is aware.

More info: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-743265157

Comment: Any explanation for this? BTW, I added it and got the same error.

Comment: @RumburaK check this out https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-743265157

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a bug from `firebase-android-sdk` or `flutter-geolocator`

if you can try to remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base`.

you can check [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662) for more information.

Comment: I don't have it and still I get the error.