# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@2178976

Tags: java, flutter, dart

This exception occur when i run the app and take so much time in launching after the debug app is installed even face problem in reload or restart

```
Exception thrown while unbinding
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@2178976
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1334)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1504)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:648)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):1)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):2)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at lu.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):9)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at le.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):3)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at eg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):3)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    W/ConnectionTracker( 1429):     at iz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714050@20.47.14 (040406-0):5)
    D/NativeCrypto( 1429): ssl=0x7b40529d40 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check out my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/64747325/5408464.

**TLDR:** This is just a minor logcat warning and should not have any effect on your app. It is a bug and the team is aware.

More info: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-743265157