# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ls@1ff721a

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

I'm using [firebase_messaging 7.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) and [flutter_local_notifications 4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to send a notification in android, everything is working fine and I also using SQLite to save Notification, it's still working fine unless background mode I can see Notification come but look like the function that I created for saving Notification not called.

code handle notification

```
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    MessageNotification notification = MessageNotification(
        id: null,
        title: message['notification']['title'],
        body: message['notification']['body'],
        status: 'U',
        createdDate: formatted);
    await dbHelper.save(notification);

    showNotification(
        message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
    messages = await dbHelper.getMessages();
    if (messages.isEmpty) {
      messages = [];
    }
    update();

    print("onLaunch: $message");
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    showNotification(
        message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    showNotification(
        message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
    messages = await dbHelper.getMessages();
    update();
  },
);
```

}

code handle background save

```
Database db;
const String ID = 'id';
const String TITLE = 'title';
const String BODY = 'body';
const String STATUS = 'status';
const String CREATEDDATE = 'createdDate';
const String TABLE = 'Message';
const String DB_NAME = 'message2.db';
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print('on background running');
  MessageNotification notification = MessageNotification(
      id: null,
      title: "Hello",
      body: "hello",
      status: 'U',
      createdDate: "2020-10-2020");

  await db.insert(TABLE, notification.toMap());


  return Future<void>.value();

  // Or do other work.
}
```

Application.java

```
public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
}

@Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"));
    PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"));
    SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));
}
```

}

errors log

```
W/ConnectionTracker(25834): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(25834): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: 
ls@1ff721a
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
lt.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
ld.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(25834):     at 
iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@205016100@20.50.16 (150700-0):5)
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer in this question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64747325/5408464